# get "onclick" url value with nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nokogiri

The `anchor` variable content this link:

```
anchor = <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="cvt-nowrap" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://url.com/persona/WebLinkEntryPoint.php?idowner=36054&amp;code=DetalleOferta&amp;idofe=140543&amp;no_links=true', '', 'left=10, top=10, width=1200, height=860, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, menubar=no, toolbar=no, directories=no, location=no, status=no'); return false;"><img src="http://static.cvtools.com/public/static/abantia/images/2013-04-02-11-14-50.7705_link.gif" border="0" align="absmiddle">Here text</a>
```

I'm using [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) gem and I would like to know if is possible extract the next url for this link:

```
http://url.com/persona/WebLinkEntryPoint.php?idowner=36054&code=DetalleOferta&idofe=140544&no_links=true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nokogiri is a html parser. the url in the onclick handler is javascript. nokogiri is not going to parse that for you, so you will have to do that on your own. through a regular expression for example:

```
html = %q(<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="cvt-nowrap" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://url.com/persona/WebLinkEntryPoint.php?idowner=36054&amp;code=DetalleOferta&amp;idofe=140543&amp;no_links=true', '', 'left=10, top=10, width=1200, height=860, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, menubar=no, toolbar=no, directories=no, location=no, status=no'); return false;"><img src="http://static.cvtools.com/public/static/abantia/images/2013-04-02-11-14-50.7705_link.gif" border="0" align="absmiddle">Here text</a>)
doc = Nokogiri.parse html
doc.xpath('//a[@onclick]').first.attributes['onclick'].content.match(/'([^']+)/)[1]
=> "http://url.com/persona/WebLinkEntryPoint.php?idowner=36054&code=DetalleOferta&idofe=140543&no_links=true"
```

Comment: I have the link in a variable called anchor. I try this: `html = %q(anchor)` but I get error. I have edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: if you already have the html in some kind of variable, just use that instead of `html`. `%q()` is just another way to write a single quoted string like `''`